# Can not connect to Redis besides from localhost

Tags: .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Hello i am using Redis and i am not able to connect to it when i am using a domain except localhost.

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'No connection is
>   available to service this operation: HEXISTS files; UnableToConnect on
>   [someDomain.com]:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted,
>   last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 1s
>   ago, last-write: 1s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10
>   of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v:
>   2.0.593.37019; IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=8,Max=32767), Local-CPU: n/a'

The multiplexer connects and also the flag is of `IsConnecting` is false.So the connection is done.

```
class Program {

       // public const string CON = "127.0.0.1:6379,ssl=False,allowAdmin=True,abortConnect=False,defaultDatabase=0";
        public const string CON = "someDomain.com:6379,ssl=False,allowAdmin=True,abortConnect=False,defaultDatabase=0";

        public static async Task<bool> LockFileForEditAsync(int fileId) {
            var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(CON);

            var flag = multiplexer.IsConnecting;
            var database = multiplexer.GetDatabase();
            var exists = await database.HashExistsAsync("files", fileId); //crashes here !!
            return false;
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            int fid = 1;
            var locked = await LockFileForEditAsync(fid);
        }
    }
```

**PS** I have checked this thread regarding [thread theft](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/410) and i can not find a solution.
So why would it work to connect on localhost, and not from another computer to the same redis-server?

Comment: Please try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1:6379, I had this error for couple of days. Nothing found. Changing to localhost in connection string did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try look for this line in your redis server's configuration file

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

If found, comment it out and restart the redis server.